# $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}≥\frac{3}{1+(\frac{x+y}{2})^2}$ if $x^2+y^2=1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Show that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}≥\frac{3}{1+(\frac{x+y}{2})^2}$. It is given that $x^2+y^2=1$. $x,y$ are positive real numbers. 
[From a Regional Mathematical Olympiad, 2013 in India]

Comment: What contest is this question from? (i.e. please cite the source). Secondly has the contest expired? (I.e. if the contest is ongoing, please delete it and post it, if you're still interested AFTER the contest is over.

Comment: Dit you try to combine LHS into one fraction and simplifying?

Comment: I would try something like $x=cos(a),y=sin(a)$

Comment: @amWhy this a question from a Regional Mathematical Olympiad paper.

Comment: @R.D. ...which took place when?  We are most welcome of contest-questions, provided the source is cited, and the contest is over at the time of the post.    Please understand, I'm really not trying to "single-you-out"...Just that in the future, it will be easier on us all if you name your source, in your post, along with the date/dates over which the competition took place.

Comment: @amWhy It took place in 2013 in some region in India.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions...Again, please understand that I wasn't targeting you, specifically.  And thanks for editing your post to include the info on the contest! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}\ge \frac{4}{1+x^2+1+y^2} + \frac{1}{1+xy}$$

Use of AM-HM Inequality for $n=2$

$$=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{1+xy} \ge \frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}}$$

Expanding out

$$\frac{7+4xy}{3(1+xy)} \ge \frac{4}{5+2xy}$$

Common Denominators

$$(7+4xy)(5+2xy) \ge 12(1+xy)$$

Justified through positive terms

$$(7+4u)(5+2u) \ge 12(1+u)$$

$$35+34u+8u^2 \ge 12+12u$$

$$8u^2 + 22u + 23 \ge 0$$

But the global minimum of the LHS is $\frac{63}{8}$ for all real values of $u$. So the inequality is strictly true for all valid $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}\ge\frac{3}{1+(\frac{x+y}{2})^2} \rightarrow \frac{1+x^2+1+y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}+\frac{1}{1+xy}\ge\frac{3}{1+(\frac{x+y}{2})^2}  \rightarrow \frac{3}{2+x^2y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}\ge\frac{3}{1+(\frac{x+y}{2})^2}  \rightarrow \frac{3+3xy+2+2x^2y^2}{2+2xy+x^2y^2+x^3y^3}\ge \frac{12}{4+x^2+y^2+2xy}  \rightarrow \frac{5+3xy+2x^2y^2}{2+2xy+x^2y^2+x^3y^3}\ge \frac{12}{5+2xy}.$$ 
 Consider $xy=z$ then we have:
$$\frac{5+3z+2z^2}{2+2z+z^2+z^3}\ge \frac{12}{5+2z}. $$ We know that $$x^2+y^2 \ge 2 (\sqrt{x^2y^2})\rightarrow -0.5\le z \le 0.5 \rightarrow (5+2z)\ge 0, (z+1)\ge 0, (1+2z) \ge 0$$. So we have:
$$\frac{5+3z+2z^2}{2+2z+z^2+z^3} - \frac{12}{5+2z}\ge 0 \rightarrow \frac{25+25z+16z^2+4z^3-24-24z-12z^2-12z^3}{(2+2z+z^2+z^3)(5+2z)} \rightarrow \frac{1+z+4z^2-8z^3}{(z+1)(2+z^2)(5+2z)}\ge 0 \rightarrow 1+z+4z^2-8z^3 \ge 0 \rightarrow (1+z) + 4z^2(1-2z) \ge 0$$

Comment: Nice alternative. I would not have seen the clever partitioning of the cubic.